# Spark Label rollover color

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I have a group of spark label components within a VGroup.  Is there a way to change the background color to the labels when the user rolls over them? I've tried adding rollOverColor to the VGroup, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<s:VGroup>
    <s:Group rollOut="aRect.visible=false"
             rollOver="aRect.visible=true">
        <s:Rect height="100%"
                id="aRect"
                width="100%">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="red"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
        <s:Label text="This is some label"/>
    </s:Group>
</s:VGroup>
```

You could throw the group portion from the code above into it's own MXML and declare a public var text that you bind to the label's text property.  Alternatively you could do this based on states, more on that here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ff1.html